# Set color of tabified QDockWidget tabs

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a QDockWidget, and I want it's tabs(when tabified) or title bar(when not tabified) to flash between two colors.

I am currently doing the following, but only the body flashes between two colors:

```
  //Setup the array of styles for the flash:
  std::array<const char*, 2> flashStyles = {
     " background-color: lightblue; color: black;",
     " background-color: orange; color: black; "
  };
  //Setup the timer and kick it off:
  connect(m_flashTimer, &QTimer::timeout, [=]()
  {
    //Perform the flash by alternating the background:
    setStyleSheet(flashStyles[
      m_pass == 0 ? m_pass++ : m_pass--
    ]);

    update();
  });
```

I can't seem to find any properties that would allow me to change the tab color / title bar color. Do I need to set the tab color properties somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which Widget is used internally by QDockWidget to display tabs. Then use the appropriate styles with the correct selector. Probably you need to select a QTabBar which is a descendant of QDockWidget. This could look like:

```
QDockWidget QTabBar {}
```

Maybe these links can also help you:

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qdockwidget

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html